# Hasura permissions question difference between admin and user

Tags: hasura

I am trying to figure out the difference between the admin role and the user role permissions when querying a Remote Schema, they both show that they have full access. However, when doing a query the user role cannot find one of the inputs for some reason. The query is

```
query SearchFacilities($getFacilitiesInput: GetFacilitiesInput!, $startDateInput: StartDateInput!) {
  facilities(getFacilitiesInput: $getFacilitiesInput) {
    facilityID
    permitEntrances(startDateInput: $startDateInput) {
      availability {
        remaining
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running the query with the x-hasura-admin-secret it works fine. However, when I switch to the user role by setting a Bearer token for the user, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "code": "validation-failed",
        "path": "$.selectionSet.facilities.selectionSet.permitEntrances"
      },
      "message": "'permitEntrances' has no argument named 'startDateInput'"
    }
  ]
}
```

They both have the same permissions according to the UI, in the remote schema section. Any ideas on what is causing this discrepancy? Been trying to figure this one out for a while, thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: After some more digging around, I can see in the introspection, as the user, that the permitEntrances field does not have any parameters. However, for the admin role, I can see it accepts the startDateInput. Does anyone know what controls that?

Comment: I got the same issue where one nested object is not accessible by the user, but is accessible by admin. Additionally, other nested object can be access both by user and admin. I'm really confused. Did you find the solution?